# Attempting to fit Bass Model on very simple data. 'language' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

I have a simple dataframe of two columns. One column, 'Time' represents the year of observation. The second column, 'dat', represents the number of product adoptions at the time of observation.

I'd like to fit a simple Bass model to these data using the nediffuseR package in R. However, when I attempt to fit the model, I get the following error:

```
Error in storage.mode(temp) <- "double" : 
  'language' object cannot be coerced to type 'double
```

The code to reproduce this is below:

```
library(netdiffuseR)

# Sample dataframe
test_data <- data.frame(Time=c(2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016),
                        dat=c(5054,12221,22468,34817,51670,70800,94736,123650,159982,206830))

# Fit Bass Model on cumulative adoptions over time
test_fit <- fitbass(dat ~ Time, data = test_data)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I know I'm missing something obvious but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] netdiffuseR_1.22.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9            sna_2.7               pillar_1.8.1          compiler_4.2.2        tools_4.2.2           bit_4.0.5            
 [7] boot_1.3-28           MatchIt_4.5.0         lifecycle_1.0.3       tibble_3.1.8          lattice_0.20-45       viridisLite_0.4.1    
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.3       rlang_1.0.6           Matrix_1.5-3          igraph_1.3.5          DBI_1.1.3             cli_3.4.1            
[19] rstudioapi_0.14       parallel_4.2.2        SparseM_1.81          coda_0.19-4           withr_2.5.0           generics_0.1.3       
[25] vctrs_0.5.1           hms_1.1.2             networkDynamic_0.11.2 bit64_4.0.5           grid_4.2.2            tidyselect_1.2.0     
[31] glue_1.6.2            R6_2.5.1              fansi_1.0.3           vroom_1.6.0           tzdb_0.3.0            magrittr_2.0.3       
[37] backports_1.4.1       ellipsis_0.3.2        MASS_7.3-58.1         assertthat_0.2.1      utf8_1.2.2            network_1.18.0       
[43] crayon_1.5.2          statnet.common_4.7.0
```

Comment: Arguably the `fitbass` function does not take a formula (like dat  ~ Time) as argument. See `?fitbass`